# Individual datatsore query oder for large number of properties

Tags: python, google-app-engine, optimization, query-optimization, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity with more than 25 properties. Out of these 25, 15 properties are displayed in the frontend table. These table will allow to do a sorting (both ASC & DESC) on each properties.

To handle this in backend, I'm checking the order type and writing query on each property for both ASC and DESC order. To handle the 15 records sorting I'm having a lots of line code which looks similar. Only difference is the order type.

Code looks like this:

```
@classmethod
def retrieve(cls, order, limit, offset):
    if order == '-property_1':
        results = cls.query(ancestor=parent).order(-cls.property_1).fetch(limit, offset=offset)
    elif order == 'property_1':
        results = cls.query(ancestor=parent).order(cls.property_1).fetch(limit, offset=offset)
        .
        .
        .
        .
    elif order == '-property_15':
        results = cls.query(ancestor=parent).order(-cls.property_15).fetch(limit, offset=offset)
    elif order == 'property_15':
        results = cls.query(ancestor=parent).order(cls.property_15).fetch(limit, offset=offset)
```

And its creating 2 datastore index for each property.

```
- kind: EntityName
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: property_1

- kind: EntityName
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: property_1
    direction: desc
```

My question here is Is there any better way to handle this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameters you're passing always match your property names then you can replace your if statements with something like:

```
desc = False
if order[0] == '-':
  order = order[1:]
  desc = True

query = cls.query(ancestor=parent)
order = getattr(cls, order)
if desc:
  order = -order

query = query.order(order)
results = query.fetch(limit, offset=offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

**No, you are handling indexing in the correct manner.**

If your data is smaller in size and relatively bounded in growth, you could switch to client-side sorting if you want to avoid creating 15*2 indexes.

Alternatively, if the number of parents (Entity-groups) is small and you can live with eventual consistency, you could omit the ancestor=parent clause and simply filter by parent in the client. This would enable you to use the built-in indexes for properties (both order directions) and not require the composite indexes.

Comment: The first line of this answer seems to be promoting unnecessary repetitive code; there is clearly a better way of doing this (see Greg's answer).

Comment: @ChrisC73 I was only discussing the indexing/querying aspect - I've updated the first line to reflex that.

Comment: agreed; the potential number of indexes required is definitely a concern